# Jaxb2Marshaller can not serialize POJO by xsd schema: "cannot find the declaration of element"

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd, jaxb

I have some xsd schema example.xsd on which one I created pojo classes (tried auto by Jaxb IntellIj Idea, or manually).

I have purpose to serialize pojo for my spring jms service and validate one against xsd before sending.

```
//init marshaller
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
....
marshaller.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("/example.xsd"));
marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();


//trying to serialize
MyResponse res = new MyResponse();
Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = jaxb2MarshallerGenerated();
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(res, new StreamResult(outputStream));
```

My xsd looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://example/schemas">
<xs:element xmlns:sch="http://example/schemas" name="myResponse" type="sch:myResponseType"/>
<xs:complexType name="myResponseType">
<xs:sequence>
  ....
</xs:sequence>
....
```

My POJO classes looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyResponse {
//some jaxb stuff
}
```

I cant escape exception:

> cannot find the declaration of element 'myResponse

I tried without namespace and other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my POJO serialized to xml has not namespace at root element.

XSD -> create java classes at Idea fixed one

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean? Something needs to be added to generated classes? I have the same problem, but I'm not using IntelliJ.

Comment: @Line yes, generated classes should contain namespace:

..XmlType (name="someName", namespace="yourNameSpace")

and each element should contains one:

..XmlElement(name="someName2", namespace="yourNameSpace")..

Comment: OK. Thanks, but I would like to specify names rather on the package level. And one more thing, you should accept your own answer ;) https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer